# Json to Scala type - list of list of any

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, scala, playframework-2.1

I am trying to parse a json object containing array of array. A sample json looks like below -

```
val data = """
         {
           "ColumnTitles": ["Product Code","Product Name","Quantity"],
           "CellValues": [
             ["prod01","Half Shirt",2],
             ["prod02","Full Shirt",1],
             ["prod03","Jeans Pant",2]
           ]
         }
        """
val dataJson = Json.parse(data)
val cTitles = ((dataJson \ "ColumnTitles").asOpt[List[String]).get
val cValues = ((dataJson \ "CellValues").asOpt[List[List[Any]]]).get
```

I know, the last line will show compilation error, but you get the idea what I want - `Any` can be String, Int or another json object. In fact, the user will send some arbitrary table data for which number of columns, number of rows, column data type - everything is unknown at compile time and should be determined based on data at run-time. How can I achieve the expected result? I have tried with Array[Array[Any]] and other possibilities.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the demarshalling of *Any*. There is no reader for that type, while Scala requires one compile time. You cannot defer that to run-time. There are two possible solutions for this problem:

- You could pick another type that a reader exists for, such as JsValue. The line then becomes:

  `val cValues = ((dataJson \ "CellValues").asOpt[List[List[JsValue]]]).get`
- You could provider a reader for the type *Any*. A reader for your example piece of code would like this:

  ```
  implicit val anyReads = new Reads[Any] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Any] = json match {
      case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(s)
      case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(n.toLong)
      case _ => JsError()
    }
  }

  val cValues = ((dataJson \ "CellValues").asOpt[List[List[Any]]]).get
  ```

  Because the *anyReads* is implicit, you don't have to specify it as argument to the *asOpt* method.

Comment: *"You cannot defer that to run-time."* Well, actually I guess this could be deferred to runtime although hardly it's recommended https://stackoverflow.com/a/64106568/5249621