# How to reflect concrete return types for methods of classes defined at runtime using the Scala ToolBox?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

When reflecting the `foo()` method of the class `Cls` we can easily get the concrete return type using the following.

```scala
class Cls {
  def foo() =
    List("A", "B")
}

val classType = ru.typeOf[Cls]
val classMirror = toolbox.mirror.reflectClass(classType.typeSymbol.asClass)
val ctorSymbol = classType.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val methodSymb = classType.decl(ru.TermName("foo")).asMethod
val ctor = classMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSymbol)
val instance = ctor()
val im = toolbox.mirror.reflect(instance)
val foo = im.reflectMethod(methodSymb)
println(foo())  // List(A, B)
println(methodSymb.returnType) // List[String]
```

However, if we define the class `Cls` at runtime via the toolbox and then use the same method reflection process, we will only get the abstract return type (`List`) of the `foo()` method.

```scala
import ru._

val tree =
  q"""class Cls {
        def foo() =
          List("A", "B")
    }""".asInstanceOf[ru.ClassDef]

val classSymbol = toolbox.define(tree).asClass
val classType = classSymbol.selfType

val classMirror = toolbox.mirror.reflectClass(classType.typeSymbol.asClass)
val ctorSymbol = classType.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val methodSymb = classType.decl(ru.TermName("foo")).asMethod
val ctor = classMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSymbol)
val instance = ctor()
val im = toolbox.mirror.reflect(instance)
val foo = im.reflectMethod(methodSymb)
println(foo())  // List("A", "B")
println(methodSymb.returnType)  // List
```

Why do these code snippets produce different results?

How can we reflect the concrete return type of the `foo()` method if `Cls` is defined at runtime using the toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the thing is in type erasure.

Try to replace

```
val classType = classSymbol.selfType
```

with

```
val classType = toolbox.eval(q"scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[$classSymbol]").asInstanceOf[ru.Type]
```

Then `methodSymb.returnType` is `List[String]`.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Would you be willing to share some more details (or pointers to docs) that explain why the type erasure would be different between these two options? Accepted either way.

Comment: @Erp12 Well, I'm not 100% sure (it would be necessary to debug toolbox code generation deeper) but my guess is as follows. Let's think about code workflow. There is compile time and runtime of main code. With toolbox inside the runtime of main code there appear compile time and runtime of toolbox. At toolbox compile time return type is `List[String]`, at toolbox runtime it's just `List[_]` because of erasure.

Comment: @Erp12 I suspect that when we do `classSymbol.selfType` we work at toolbox runtime while with `toolbox.eval(q"scala.reflect...` we capture a type from toolbox compile time (`tb.eval(tree)` is `tb.compile(tree).apply()`). Toolbox doesn't allow to control better code generation. I guess with manual code generation (see [code](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/f2f859273075370c4687a30e0c3a2431) from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111895/dynamically-parse-json-in-flink-map)) you have better control how you compile and run your code.

Comment: @Erp12  In that question I already had a situation when I had to capture some type information from within the toolbox with `eval` (see code snippet in my answer to that question with `tb.eval(q"...TypeInformation.of(classOf...`).